# Same key for all key-value pairs?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

Can I use the same key for all key-value pairs in a SharedPreference file in Android? (I really don't need the key). I want to access the pairs only by value. Also how long can a key be ?

Comment: Can you provide some code to explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: I have a to-do list in my project, as tasks displayed on a listview. Every task contains only a string. Onclick the task is deleted. Its as simple as that. I want to save those tasks in SharedPreferences and reload the the next time a user runs the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android allows you to store a String-Set in your SharedPreferences. I guess that's what you are looking for. See [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getStringSet(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E)).

Otherwise, you could also look into a [sqlite database](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html).

Answer (score 1):

Then we can save ArrayList in Preferences

```
 public void saveArray(ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(R.string.PREF_FILE + "", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("size", arrayList.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
            editor.putString("task" + i, arrayList.get(i));

        }

        editor.commit();
    }
```